# Can't change your vote after an hour?

Tags: feature-request, status-bydesign, voting

It seems like if you vote something up or down, after an hour that is fixed and you cannot change it - this is irritating because people are still able to edit their post after an hour. Can we change this please?

Comment: [Please get rid of “vote locking”](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/5120/2206)

Answer (score 6):

You are allowed to change your vote only when a post has been edited since you last voted, or within several minutes of your previous vote. This system has had a lot of discussion in relation to Stack Overflow, and has generally worked pretty well.

Comment: The system on MathOverflow works just as well (it's several hours instead of several minutes).  It allows you to "seed" votes up or down and remove them if you need more votes later.  The vote limit is too low for the "several minutes" system.  For example, say I wasted all of my votes for the day on a community wiki question, then I want to vote down a spam post.  On MO, I can just remove my votes on the CW posts and reuse them somewhere else.  Here, I do not have that ability (see the meta.MO discussion about problems with SE2.0).

Comment: @97832123: Edit the community wiki posts. Then you will be able to retract your votes.

Comment: @978 I view that sort of voting behavior as a bit abusive and game-y. That's why the limit for changing is currently 5 minutes, or infinite if there is an edit.

Comment: @97832123: (Fancy changing your username to something more readable?) This is clearly a subjective point, but I'm with Mr. Atwood on this one.

Comment: @Jeff: Shouldn't each community be allowed to vote on exactly how long we can change votes for?